# How to deal with duplicate rows in SQL?

Tags: sql

The table has duplicate IDs from a large table. I want to get one output for each ID. What's the best way to do it?

MyTable

```
ID Col1 Col2
1    X    A
1    Y    B
1    Z    C
2    X    D
2    Y    E
3    Z    F
3    W    G
If Col1 = 'X' and Col2 ='A', then 'Y' is the output for ID1
If Col1 = 'X' and Col2 !='A', then 'N' is the output for ID2
If Col1 != 'X', then 'Y' is the output for ID3
```

Comment: Each ID should be unique in a database. What you should do is make it a primary key. Then you would not have duplicates.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Please tag your SQL dialect/version. Then just use the standard `case when`.

Comment: I get this data from multiple tables join. The tables are stored in SQL Server Data Warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

```
If Col1 = 'X' and Col2 ='A', then 'Y' is the output for ID1
If Col1 = 'X' and Col2 !='A', then 'N' is the output for ID2
If Col1 != 'X', then 'Y' is the output for ID3
```

I assume the conditions above need to be true for only 1 row per id. You can use conditional aggregation to check whether the condition applies to at least 1 row per group:

```
select id,
case when count(case when Col1 = 'X' and Col2 = 'A' then 1 end) > 0 then 'Y'
when count(case when Col1 = 'X' and Col2 <> 'A' then 1 end) > 0 then 'N'
when count(case when Col1 = 'X' then 1 end) > 0 then 'Y'
else '?'
end as output
from mytable
group by id
```

Comment: It displays multiple rows, not single row per group.